# How to put this cursor data in ArrayLists - AndroidStudio

Tags: android, arraylist, android-studio

I have a cursorLoader which returns a cursor with this data:

```
    0 {
    email=bogdan@gmail.com
    about=Party
    }
    1 {
    email=bogdan1@gmail.com
    about=Paaarty
    }
    2 {
    email=bogdan2@gmail.com
    about=activity 2
    }
    3 {
    email=bogdan3@gmail.com
    about=activity 3
    }
    4 {
    email=bogdan4@gmail.com
    about=activity 5
    }
```

How can I save the emails in an ArrayList called emails and the about in an ArrayList called about. I've been trying different things with the cursor but most of the time I just get outOfBounds.

Edit: This is the line that prints it like that:

```
Log.v("Cursor Object", DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(cursor));
```

Comment: why do you want to do that?

Comment: Pass it into a list. I get this data from the server. The list is working. Before doing this instead of storing the data I was just saving it directly in ArrayLists and passing it between activities.  Now I stored it in a database using a content provider and I get it with a loader. The problem is that I don't know how to put it into ArrayLists anymore. My list has a custom adapter which takes 2 ArrayList as parameters and populate the list.

Comment: wrong,  use a SimpleCursorAdapter

Comment: I thought about that, but I had everything done and I went for the easier solution. I'll look into it. What's the difference between storing it and then using it from ArrayLists and using it directly into a CursorAdapter ? Is it just the waste of resources and time ?

Comment: I have a ListView and a PagerView both using this data. Can I use the SimpleCursorAdapter for both ?

Comment: for ViewPager use https://gist.github.com/mlc/2975296 or similar adapter

Comment: and of course SimpleCursorAdapter is an easier solution: no need to additional lists, no need for a custom adapter, automatic ListView update when data changes in the db, no waste of resources and cpu time

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate it. One more question: I was starting the ViewPager when clicking on a listItem and it would let me navigate through the ViewPager because they had the same items. Do you think I can do the same again ?

Comment: i am not sure what you mean

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79930/discussion-between-bogdan-daniel-and-pskink).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it your way maybe this method would help (provided that you supply two empty `ArrayList`) ?

```
private void populateLists(Cursor cursor, List<String> emails,
        List<String> about) throws IllegalArgumentException {

    if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        do {
            emails.add(cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow("email")));
            about.add(cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow("about")));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it if I fail using @pskink's method. I think the way he said to do it is better.

Comment: yes definitely, @pskinks's method is the preferred way to do :-)

Comment: your method is working. I tested it. I ended up using this because I  had no idea how to perform operations on elements when using a SimpleCursorAdapter. My CustomAdapter is much more flexible. What are the downsides of using this method: storing them in arrayLists and passing them in the CustomAdapter instead of using a SimpleCursorAdapter ?

Comment: I'm happy that it works, cause I didn't test it ;-) (but was actually pretty sure it would). If you need an example of how a `SimpleCursorAdapter` works take a look at this reference and demo: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html#example

Comment: I don't really understand how I can address specific elements before the loading and modify them